# Delete Google App Engine Account

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to delete the account I have with Google App Engine since I don't use it and I also would like to stop receiving email from Google regarding this account and policies update and alike.

Is there a way to do this?

UPD:

I raised this issue in google issue tracking system and it has been accepted as a valid feature request. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5745

UPD2:

A nice person from Google offered his help in deleting of my account as soon as I remove any apps I have there. Thanks for that!

Comment: +1 for rising issue in the official issue tracking.

Answer (score 3):

A note from [Google accouts TOS](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS):

> 13.2 If you want to terminate your legal agreement with Google, you
>   may do so by (a) notifying Google at any time and (b) closing your
>   accounts for all of the Services which you use, where Google has made
>   this option available to you. Your notice should be sent, in writing,
>   to Google’s address which is set out at the beginning of these Terms.

By myself I didn't found how one can delete google app Engine account, so *it's possible* that this is not `Services which you use, where Google has made this option available to you`. As other option I see is to ask on [Googl App Engine community question board](http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html), and hope that google moderators read those question.